# Count number of files, pause, and move files

Tags: batch-file

I want to write 1 batch file such that it counts no of files in folder1 and if that count is equals to 15 then wait for 10 min and then move all that files to folder2

```
set cmd=“dir /s /b D:\DAILY_FLAT_FILES\inbox\original_files\*.gz |find /c ”\“ ”
```

Comment: Please rename your question to something meaningful, possibly related to the nature of your problem and post details in the body.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:repeat
for /f %%a in ('dir "folder1\"^| find "File(s)"') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
if %count% leq 15 (
 echo files are 15 or less
 PING -n 601 127.0.0.1>nul
 goto :repeat

)
echo copying the files
copy "folder1\*"  "folder2\"
```

Comment: You may have to add `timeout /t 600` before `echo copying the files` to make it wait for 10 minutes before moving the files to folder2

Comment: yeees..Totally forgot.

Comment: I think the OP wants to wait 10 minutes **after** the count reaches 15, too.

Comment: try this instead `set /a cnt=0 && for %a in (*) do set /a cnt+=1`