# How to check if a folder has more than 20 files in it in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I want to write an batchfile that Deletes a folder
if the folder has more than 20 files in it. but I do not know how to do it.

I use Windows7 Ultimate.

Comment: Search here for `[batch-file] count files`. The very first hit is http://stackoverflow.com/q/19446113, which shows how to count the files (among other things). Please search here first before posting a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the files in bare format and use `find` command to count the number of output lines

```
set "nFiles=0"
for /f %%a in (
    'dir /a-d /b "c:\folder\*" 2^>nul ^| find /c /v ""'
) do set "nFiles=%%a"
echo %nFiles%
```

List the files in usual format and use `findstr` to locate the line/field with the number of files

```
set "nFiles="
for /f %%a in (
    'dir "c:\folder\*" ^| findstr /b /c:"  "'
) do if not defined nFiles set "nFiles=%%a"
if not defined nFiles set "nFiles=0"
echo %nFiles%
```

Use a counter over the output of `dir` command

```
set "nFiles=0"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "c:\folder\*" 2>nul ') do set /a "nFiles+=1"
echo %nFiles%
```

Or you can use `wmic`, or number the lines in the output of `dir` command with the usage of `findstr /n`, or ....

In any case

```
if %nFiles% gtr 20 rd /s /q "c:\folder"
```